# Smart Contract name as datatype in Solidity

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am following a tutorial.
In that i imported one contract to another contract.
Then i used the name of imported contract as the datatype name to initialise an array.
**How is it possible to use a contract name as datatype ?.**

```
import "./SimpleStorage.sol"; //importing another contract

contract StorageFactory {
    SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray ; //global variable
    function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
        simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage);
    }

    function sfStore(uint256 _simpleStorageIndex, uint256 _simpleStorageNumber) public {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex];  
        simpleStorage.store(_simpleStorageNumber);
    }

    function sfGet(uint256 _simpleStorageIndex) public view returns(uint256){
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = simpleStorageArray[_simpleStorageIndex];
        return simpleStorage.retrieve();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Contract and interface type acts as a pointer to the target contract. The code assumes that the target contract implements all `external` and `public` functions of this type.

In your case, `StorageFactory` assumes that all addresses stored in the `simpleStorageArray` array implement the interface of `SimpleStorage`.

So if `SimpleStorage` implement this function: `get() external returns (uint256)`, `StorageFactory` is going to expect this function to return a binary response with the length of 256 bits, and then cast it to unsigned integer.

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/types.html#contract-types